# WSL Rails Selenium Chromedriver connection refused for localhost 9515

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When running cucumber feature tests in Rails on WSL returns:

**Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9515) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)**

After trying to run Selenium on Ubuntu without success then reading this artile [Chrome doesn't start in WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) with "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" under Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047981/chrome-doesnt-start-in-wsl-ubuntu-18-04-with-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt/59444992#59444992) I tried this configuration:

```
Capybara.register_driver :windows_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome()
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,browser: :chrome, url: 'http://localhost:9515',
                                     desired_capabilities: capabilities)
  end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :windows_chrome
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5 # Seconds
```

- Windows 10 Version 10.0.19041.84
- Chrome installed in Windows Version 80.0.3987.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Chromedriver 80.0.3987.16 in Windows 10 on port 9515
- Visiting localhost:9515 in Chrome returns: {"value":{"error":"unknown command","mes...
- Ubuntu 18.0.4
- cat /etc/resolv.conf returns: 172.19.160.1
- Ruby 2.6.3p62
- Rails 6.0.1
- capybara (3.29.0)
- selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
- webdrivers (4.1.3)
- sudo ufw status numbered returns: Status: inactive
- Windows Firewall disabled
- Windows Defender disabled
- no antivirus running

echo 'It works' | nc -4 -v localhost 9515
nc: connect to localhost port 9515 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

echo 'It works' | nc -4 -v 172.19.160.1 9515
nc: connect to 172.19.160.1 port 9515 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out

When using 172.19.160.1 (WSL2 IP) in Capybara also get timed out.

What could be preventing the connection on port 9515?

**UPDATE**
From this post [When running WebDriver with Chrome browser, getting message, "Only local connections are allowed" even though browser launches properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect)

I found a work around.  If I start Chromedriver like this, I can run the tests:
`chromedriver.exe --whitelisted-ips=""`
Not ideal; still looking for way to determine which address and ports are being used.  May actually be IPV6 not IPV4?

Comment: I have never developed on a windows environment, but when i faced this issue on my macbook it was due to selenium process from a previous run not quitting the port. As a result the port is not available for the new process to latch. Try checking for active chromedriver / webdriver processes and closing them.